# Can't use own class in Service class

Tags: android, service

I have FileWriteReadHelper class. And want to use it in MyService service.
I tried

```
FileWriteReadHelper writer = FileWriteReadHelper();
```

But FileWriteReadHelper is underlined with message :

```
The method FileWriteReadHelper() is undefined for the type MyService
```

Any ideas to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with:

```
FileWriteReadHelper writer = new FileWriteReadHelper(); // <-------- new added
```